# How to get data from "Web Mysql Database" and send it to "localhost (XAMPP) mysql database"?

Tags: php, mysql

1. I have a web page and mysql tables in there... My customers create some datas at there and I save them to my web database...
2. I have localhost in my computer and I wanna get those datas to my local database with a "button" or etc... is it possible?

> I use PHP with PDO...

More detail:

[image]

Comment: Does your web database feature a phpmyadmin interface? if not please let me know.

Comment: sure.. phpmyadmin and there is a system working with PHP PDO...

Comment: Do you want to take a copy of the database once or do you want to take regular copies

Comment: I have same logic system in my localhost....

Comment: _"is it possible?"_ - Yes. You can create an API endpoint on the server that returns the data you need from the database. Then you can create a local page with a "button", which triggers a call to the API, retrieves the response and inserts it into your local database.

Comment: I added an explanation image to question

Comment: The problem is I have no idea about that way.. I create system for both localhost and webserver.. both have connect "$connection = new PDO( 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=musteri', $username, $password );"  but I just need to connect both of them together...

Comment: Why do you need **two** systems after all? Why not work on **one** system to avoid problems with out-of-sync data?

Comment: webserver = for customers.. localhost is for security...

Comment: I dont want anyone that can reach my team workings datas...

Comment: Your images proposes that the admin for the remote system will push data into the local database. It should be the other way around. The local system fetches the necessary data from the remote server. Unless the admin for the remote site is located insde your local environment.

Comment: admin means who have acess to insert into web database project to localhost will sit on the localhost computer... actualyy I also will need to change web server datas from localhost.. so I need to find the way that talk "localhost and web server together as 1 server"

Comment: Why not use **one server** for this?

Comment: webserver = for customers.. localhost is for security and speed...

Comment: And your customers do not deserve security and speed? That sounds pretty strange

Comment: of course , customers page also have security and speed.. but as you appriciate web servers have always risky than localhost.. so my factory inside system has to be more more and more security and speed.. so if I can do that why I dont?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "secure" here? If you copy the data from the remote server to a local server, it will still exist in both places so it won't be more secure. And what exactly is the issue with "speed"? Speed of what exactly? If you give us some real details, it might be easier for us to understand the problem. The image doesn't really explain much. And I've already gave you a suggestion about how you can fetch the data, but you never commented on that.

Answer (score -1):

Simply export database from wherever you have it on your web and import it on localhost/phpmyadmin through xampp.

Comment: thanks but it doesnt work for my stuation..

Comment: That does not sound like a good long-term solution if May wants to work with the data locally without overwriting it

Comment: Hi, this does not seem much like an answer, since it does not solve the problem in question, but more like comment.